# SAS EG 7.1 Automation using .NET

Tags: .net, sas, enterprise-guide

I'm trying to schedule a project, but I'm unable to run VBScript due to privilege restriction on my PC. I want to create a program using C# that takes the place of the VBScript that is automatically generated by SAS EG when using the "Schedule Program" option.

Chris Hemedinger wrote [a paper on automation for SAS EG 5.1](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/examples/SASGF2012/Hemedinger_298-2012.pdf), which was useful for finding the correct .dll to reference in my C# Project. However, the reference provided in that paper to the scripting documentation links to the general EG documentation site.

Is there scripting documentation available for SAS EG 7.1?

Comment: Can you run Powershell scripts?  That may be easier... in any event, I suspect the documentation exists but I don't know where.  You might post on Chris's blog on one of the relevant posts ([The SAS Dummy](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/)) - that might be the best place, he undoubtedly knows.

Comment: @Joe It looks like I am able to run PowerShell Scripts, so that could very well be an option. Thanks for the suggestion! Hopefully someone comes along who knows where the documentation exists, but I will post on Chris's blog as well.

Comment: Additionally, if you post on communities.sas.com Chris can point you towards any relevant reference. Chris is now the SAS communities manager.

Comment: I posted on communities.sas.com and Chris answered within minutes. Posting an answer here shortly with the link he provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripting documentation for SAS EG can be found here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/SASEGScripting42.zip

In Windows the .chm file will not work immediately after extracting it from the .zip. You will need to right click the file, select properties, and then unblock.